# Wininet.dll repeatedly causes explorer.exe and dllhost.exe to crash

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, windows-explorer, crash, linux-kvm

I am using SUSE's Harvester to run virtual machines (It uses KVM). Using that, I created a virtual machine with a Windows 10 Pro installation (22H2).

Today when I restored the vm from a VM snapshot, explorer.exe kept crashing. Even taskmanager occasionally crashed. Through task manager I was able to do the following things:

- kill explorer.exe so that it didn't keep trying (and failing) to restart
- open Windows Terminal (thank god)
- open explorer.exe (it keeps crashing if you just start it, but if you start it in a specific folder instead, the actual File Explorer window does show up without crashing)
- open the old windows 7 Control Panel (through right-clicking network in File Explorer)
- open Event Viewer

I was unable to open the Windows 10 settings (through right-clicking This PC in File Explorer or through the command line in Windows Terminal)

Also, the computer shuts itself down at some point. I think that this might be caused by explorer.exe being turned off for too long, but I don't know for sure.

From Event Viewer I learned that wininet.dll was responsible (or at least involved) in the crash. Every program that I saw in the list of crashes referred to wininet.dll. Dllhost.exe also seems to crash a lot due to this issue with wininet.dll.

Knowing this however doesn't really help me as I don't really know what could be causing wininet.dll to crash.

That's why I'm asking here on SU: what could be the reason for the crashes and more importantly: how can I fix this issue?

Here is the virtual machine configuration:

```yaml
apiVersion: kubevirt.io/v1
kind: VirtualMachine
metadata:
  annotations:
    field.cattle.io/description: '<vm description>'
    harvesterhci.io/reservedMemory: 256Mi
    harvesterhci.io/vmRunStrategy: RerunOnFailure
    kubevirt.io/latest-observed-api-version: v1
    kubevirt.io/storage-observed-api-version: v1alpha3
    network.harvesterhci.io/ips: '[]'
    restore.harvesterhci.io/last-restore-uid: restore-windows-10-clean-install-8q88l-522856a9-fba0-40aa-ab66-b328830cc14f
    restore.harvesterhci.io/name: restore-windows-10-clean-install-8q88l
  creationTimestamp: "2023-01-03T23:11:55Z"
  finalizers:
  - wrangler.cattle.io/VMController.UnsetOwnerOfPVCs
  generation: 6
  labels:
    harvesterhci.io/creator: harvester
    harvesterhci.io/os: windows
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: kubevirt.io/v1alpha3
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          f:kubevirt.io/latest-observed-api-version: {}
          f:kubevirt.io/storage-observed-api-version: {}
    manager: Go-http-client
    operation: Update
    time: "2023-01-07T15:25:12Z"
  - apiVersion: kubevirt.io/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:field.cattle.io/description: {}
          f:harvesterhci.io/reservedMemory: {}
          f:harvesterhci.io/vmRunStrategy: {}
          f:network.harvesterhci.io/ips: {}
          f:restore.harvesterhci.io/last-restore-uid: {}
          f:restore.harvesterhci.io/name: {}
        f:finalizers:
          .: {}
          v:"wrangler.cattle.io/VMController.UnsetOwnerOfPVCs": {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:harvesterhci.io/creator: {}
          f:harvesterhci.io/os: {}
      f:spec:
        .: {}
        f:runStrategy: {}
        f:template:
          .: {}
          f:metadata:
            .: {}
            f:annotations:
              .: {}
              f:harvesterhci.io/sshNames: {}
            f:creationTimestamp: {}
            f:labels:
              .: {}
              f:harvesterhci.io/vmName: {}
          f:spec:
            .: {}
            f:accessCredentials: {}
            f:affinity:
              f:nodeAffinity:
                f:preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution: {}
            f:domain:
              .: {}
              f:cpu:
                .: {}
                f:cores: {}
              f:devices:
                .: {}
                f:disks: {}
                f:hostDevices: {}
                f:inputs: {}
                f:interfaces: {}
              f:features:
                .: {}
                f:acpi:
                  .: {}
                  f:enabled: {}
              f:machine: {}
              f:resources:
                .: {}
                f:limits:
                  .: {}
                  f:cpu: {}
                  f:memory: {}
            f:evictionStrategy: {}
            f:hostname: {}
            f:networks: {}
            f:nodeSelector:
              .: {}
              f:kubernetes.io/hostname: {}
            f:volumes: {}
    manager: harvester
    operation: Update
    time: "2023-01-07T15:30:15Z"
  - apiVersion: kubevirt.io/v1alpha3
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        .: {}
        f:conditions: {}
        f:created: {}
        f:printableStatus: {}
        f:ready: {}
        f:volumeSnapshotStatuses: {}
    manager: Go-http-client
    operation: Update
    subresource: status
    time: "2023-01-07T15:51:40Z"
  name: <vm name>
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "9944363"
  uid: 8f4632c7-08b2-4045-a180-9e42a7188c75
spec:
  runStrategy: RerunOnFailure
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        harvesterhci.io/sshNames: '[]'
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        harvesterhci.io/vmName: <vm name>
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: network.harvesterhci.io/mgmt
                operator: In
                values:
                - "true"
      domain:
        cpu:
          cores: 4
        devices:
          disks:
          - bootOrder: 1
            cdrom:
              bus: sata
            name: cdrom-disk
          - bootOrder: 2
            disk:
              bus: sata
            name: rootdisk
          inputs:
          - bus: usb
            name: tablet
            type: tablet
          interfaces:
          - bridge: {}
            macAddress: <inet mac address>
            model: e1000
            name: default
        features:
          acpi:
            enabled: true
        machine:
          type: q35
        memory:
          guest: 16128Mi
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "4"
            memory: 16Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 10922Mi
      evictionStrategy: LiveMigrate
      hostname: <vm name>
      networks:
      - multus:
          networkName: default/lan
        name: default
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/hostname: <host name>
      volumes:
      - name: cdrom-disk
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: restore-windows-10-clean-install-522856a9-fba0-40aa-ab66-b328830cc14f-cdrom-disk
      - name: rootdisk
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: restore-windows-10-clean-install-522856a9-fba0-40aa-ab66-b328830cc14f-rootdisk
```

Screenshot of the errors in Event viewer:
[image: Explorer error]

[image: Dllhost error]

Comment: What is the Virtual Machine App you are using?  How did you build your Windows 10 Virtual Machine?  I have a Windows 10 Pro Virtual Machine in VMware Workstation Pro and it does not crash.

Comment: I added to the question that Harvester uses KVM and that it was a Win10 Pro installation. For me it also used to not crash, but after I force-changed the DHCP IP address on my router, Windows kept blue-screening. That's why I reverted it back to an older snapshot. That's when the issues started.

Comment: The issues with the IP address seemed to have been resolved by reverting to the older snapshot, because I was able to remote-desktop into the machine using the new IP address.

Comment: Interesting.  I have not had IP addressing issues with Hyper-V or with VMware. So I cannot assist further.